# Winter 23 Named Credentials: no authentication

Tags: namedcredentials, winter23

Now that Named Credentials have added External Credentials as the extra layer of authentication, is it still possible to have Named Credentials with No Authentication? It would appear that the External Credential field is mandatory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have to specify an external credential, you can define an external credential with a protocol of `Custom`. You don't need to specify a username or password.